# "Cannot add foreign key constraint" on Spring Data JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I try to execute my spring boot project, I get the error message on the title. It is an MySQL error, I know but I do not want to deal with creating and altering the table on MySQL development. Here is the MySQL command executed in my project:

```
alter table password_reset_token add constraint FK5lwtbncug84d4ero33v3cfxvl foreign key (user_id) references user (id);
```

I have USER class and table;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String email;

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

And I have an entity;

```
@Entity
public class PasswordResetToken{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String token;
  private User user;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
  public User getUser(){
    return user;
  }
  //And other Getters and Setters
}
```

Where do I make wrong? When I look at the table (password_reset_token) which is automatically generated, I do not see any foreign key and when I run the command, I get the same error on MySQL development side.

There are many "Cannot add foreign key constraint" posts but none of them addresses this problem in my case.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. It is due to data type mismatch of primary key, foreign key.

I created 'User' table and declared its primary key with INT. In the User class, I declared 'id' Long. JPA expects to get foreign key with 'BIGINT' but its type is 'INT' actually. That is why, it gives me the error. I changed the type to BIGINT and now it works.

Comment: Well this is akward... i had mine as long but it still denies the foreign key, when i create the table manually then it actually works for some reason. And by manually i mean i add the table with 1 random key thats not even in the code.

Comment: In my case JPA tries to add foreign key constraint on a non existing/before creating the user table. Strange. It might be something to do with user as reserved keyword.